# how to get kubectl configuration from azure aks with python?

Tags: python, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I create a k8s deployment script with python, and to get the configuration from `kubectl`, I use the python command:

```
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
```

to get the azure aks configuration I use the following `az` commands:

```
az login
az aks get-credentials --resource-group [resource group name] --name [aks name]
```

is there any way to get azure aks credential only from python and without the need of the `az` commands?

thanks!

Comment: yeah, use python sdk and call the same api directly (or without using sdk, just do an http request to the api). but, just doing something `subprocess.check_call('az aks get-credentials --resource-group [resource group name] --name [aks name]', shell=True)` would be a lot easier

Comment: I don't want to use the `subprocess` solution because I don't want to login to Azure in `az` command (i don't want to depend on a `az` package, only on python).

Comment: well, you have to authenticate either way, its up to you. python sdk https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python. and this is probably the call you are interested it: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt-containerservice/azure/mgmt/containerservice/operations/managed_clusters_operations.py#L246

Comment: thank you very much!
i use `list_cluster_admin_credential` to get my configuration

Comment: I don't like calling a sub process because defeats the purpose of having pythonic code. TBH, There should be a way to use [Kubectl Python Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) along with Azure Python SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the solution was to use Azure Python SDK to retrieve cluster credentials directly from Azure API bypassing Az Cli.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/containerservice/azure-mgmt-containerservice/azure/mgmt/containerservice/v2019_11_01/operations/_managed_clusters_operations.py#L320

Comment: Broken link. @4c74356b41 do you happen to have a valid link? Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/containerservice/azure-mgmt-containerservice/azure/mgmt/containerservice/v2019_11_01/operations/_managed_clusters_operations.py#L320

Comment: @4c74356b41 could you edit this to have a snippet where you use that? the lack of documentation in the azure github is driving me insane..

Comment: please create a new question for this

Comment: see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer why should I ask the same question as OP again? a link is not an answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done with the Azure Python SDK.

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_cli_credential=True)
subscription_id = os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"]
container_service_client = ContainerServiceClient(credential, subscription_id)

kubeconfig = container_service_client.managed_clusters.list_cluster_user_credentials("resourcegroup-name", "cluster-name").kubeconfigs[0]
```

Comment: Once I have received the `kubeconfig`, how do I use it with `Kubectl Python Client`? I am using `from kubernetes import client, config`. Any help appreciated much!

Answer (score 2):

Just expanding on @user1110502's excellent answer, the kubeconfig you get is a `CredentialResult` object. You can turn that into a yaml string which can then be saved as a file like below:

```py
aks_client = ContainerServiceClient(credential, subscription_id)
result: CredentialResult = aks_client.managed_clusters.list_cluster_user_credentials(
    "resourcegroup-name", "cluster-name"
).kubeconfigs[0]
kubeconfig: str = result.value.decode("utf-8")
```

To then use this config in the `kubernetes` python library you could save it as a file and load it in the usual manner with `kubernetes.config.load_kube_config`, however the same can be achieved without the unnecessary disk IO like below:

```py
import yaml
import kubernetes
from kubernetes.config.kube_config import KubeConfigLoader

cfg_dict = yaml.safe_load(kubeconfig)
loader = KubeConfigLoader(cfg_dict)
config = client.Configuration()
loader.load_and_set(config)
client.Configuration.set_default(config)
```

The `kubernetes` library can then be connected to your AKS cluster:

```py
with kubernetes.client.ApiClient(config) as api_client:
    api = client.WellKnownApi(api_client)
    resp = api.get_service_account_issuer_open_id_configuration()
    print(resp)
```