# Populate pods CPU limits using Kubernetes Python Client for Azure AKS cluster

Tags: python, azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I need to use [Azure Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) and [Kubernetes Python Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to list the Pods CPU limits for a cluster running in AKS.

Although its straight forward using CLI/PowerShell but I need to use Python exclusively.
Must not use [subprocess calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535855/how-to-get-kubectl-configuration-from-azure-aks-with-python).

Here is snippet that gets `KubeConfig` object after authentication with Azure:

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_cli_credential=True)
subscription_id = "XXX"
resource_group_name= 'MY-SUB'
cluster_name = "my-aks-clustername" 
container_service_client = ContainerServiceClient(credential, subscription_id)

kubeconfig = container_service_client.managed_clusters. \
list_cluster_user_credentials(resource_group_name, cluster_name). \
kubeconfigs[0]
```

But I am unsure how to put this to be used by K8s Python client:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config() ## How to pass? 

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `config.load_kube_config` method and pass in the kubeconfig object you obtained earlier as a parameter. The method accepts a `config_file` parameter, which can be a file object, a file-like object, or a string file path.

Since **kubeconfig** is a string, you can pass it as a string file path, like so:

```
from kubernetes import client, config

# Pass the kubeconfig string as a file path
config.load_kube_config(config_file=kubeconfig)

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

Comment: For fetching the `HPA` one should use `client.AutoscalingV2Api().list_horizontal_pod_autoscaler_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)` and iterate expression would be `i.spec.template.spec.containers[0].resources.limits.get('cpu')` and `i.spec.template.spec.containers[0].resources.limits.get('memory')`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a repro and was able to achieve as below -

1. Getting kubeconfig in correct decoded format from kubeconfigs[0] which is [CredentialResults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-hybridkubernetes/azure.mgmt.hybridkubernetes.models.credentialresults?view=azure-python).
2. Writing the generated kubeconfig in a file.
3. Loading the file in config module.

   ```
   from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
   from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient
   import os
   from kubernetes import client, config

   credential = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_cli_credential=True)
   subscription_id = "XXX"
   resource_group_name= 'MY-SUB'
   cluster_name = "my-aks-clustername" 
   container_service_client = ContainerServiceClient(credential, subscription_id)

   # getting kubeconfig in a decoded format from CredentialResult

   kubeconfig = container_service_client.managed_clusters. \
   list_cluster_user_credentials(resource_group_name, cluster_name). \
   kubeconfigs[0].value.decode(encoding='UTF-8')

   # writing generated kubeconfig in a file
   f=open("kubeconfig","w")
   f.write(kubeconfig)
   f.close()

   # loading the config file
   config.load_kube_config('kubeconfig')

   # deleting the kubeconfig file
   os.remove('kubeconfig')

   v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
   print("Listing containers with their CPU limits:")
   ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
   for i in ret.items:
     for container in i.spec.containers:
       if container.resources.limits:
         if 'cpu' in container.resources.limits:
            print( container.name, container.resources.limits['cpu'])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config() ## How to pass? 

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their CPU limits:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    for container in i.spec.containers:
        if container.resources.limits:
            if 'cpu' in container.resources.limits:
                print(container.resources.limits['cpu'])
```

Comment: Incorrect answer. The question is regarding the interfacing the Python K8s client with Azure Python config object. Please check again.

Comment: Sorry man I don't have an AKS cluster to test with/ am not familiar with Azure python config. However the logic here does the required task of listing CPU limits for pods as you asked. You should consider asking another question regarding your issue with Azure python config.